# PHP Startup Unable to load dynamic library php_mongodb.dll

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

Hello guys I'm trying to integrate mongodb with my laravel project. Since I'm new to this so I'm facing some errors when trying to intergrate the monogdb. 
I'm following this tutorial [Laravel MongoDB](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#installation). When ever I try to run this command `composer require jenssegers/mongodb` I get this error.

> Warning: Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'D:/Ampps/php/ext\php_mongodb.dll' - The specified module could not be
>   found.  in Unknown on line 0 Using version ^3.0 for jenssegers/mongodb
>   ./composer.json has been updated
>   php artisan clear-compiled
>
> Warning: Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'D:/Ampps/php/ext\php_mongodb.dll' - The specified module could not be
>   found.  in Unknown on line 0 Loading composer repositories with
>   package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your
>   requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.0 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
>       - jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.1 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
>       - jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.2 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
>       - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.0 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2].
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini
>   files:
>       - D:\Ampps\php\php.ini   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

Can't figure out why. Please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong.

one thing more that the mongodb dll that I downloaded is the correct one which matches to my php version and it is the thread safe version

If you guys have any question feel free to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why but I downloaded the file again and replaced the already present file and everything started to work. Wired but this helped me